# Update ONLY an auth.user field using request.user and django rest framework serializers

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm currently writing an API using the django rest framework for the first time.  However, I've run in to a problem when trying to update an object using only the request.user field

from what I understand, when updating an object with request.data fields, all you have to do is:

```
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
    chore = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = ChoreSerializer(chore, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

however, if I try to leave the data=request.data out, I'll get errors when trying to call .is_valid(). and in turn .save().  I managed to get around this error by serializing the object I want to change based on a primary key, and then de-serializing it again, using the serialized data like this:

```
seri = ChoreSerializer(chore)
serializer = ChoreSerializer(chore, data=seri.data)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(assigned_to=self.request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My question is whether this is actually the correct way to do this, or whether there's a better method

here's my Model:

```
class Chore(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='chores')
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='assigned_to', blank=True, null=True)
```

and here's my Serializer:

```
class ChoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Chore
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner', 'assigned_to')

owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
assigned_to = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='assigned_to.username')

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Chore.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
    instance.assigned_to = validated_data.get('assigned_to', instance.assigned_to)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: Are you using `PUT` to only update the user (meaning other field will never be changed)? If so, then you can just directly update the model instead.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Thanks!